# Update data field by field when using json encode (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am updating my data using json encode its working fine i have a password field which i want to keep in encrypted form but i don't know how to save that data field by field currently i am updating data as

```
$student_data->fill([

            'student_data'  => $data,

            ])->save();
```

Above **$data** variable have all data in it to save

it saves in a field **student_data** in json_encoded form in db field as

**student_data** db field

```
{"name":"test","username":"testuser","password":"testpassword"}
```

I want to save above password using bcrypt

How can i achive this please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try like this...

```
$json = '{"name":"test","username":"testuser","password":"testpassword"}';
$arr = (json_decode($json,true)); //converts json into array
$pass = $arr['password'];
$password = bcrypt($pass);
$arr['password'] = $password;
//print_r($arr);
$data = json_encode($arr);//back to json from array
```

And

```
$student_data->fill([

            'student_data'  => $data,

            ])->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the respective model, the password set attribute can be used like,

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    if ($password != null) {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }
}
```

It will simply inserts every record with encrypted password.